# 'Employee' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#

'Employee' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'. I can't seem to correct the 4 errors. Help anyone? Lines 12 and 27. I placed explanation on the 2 error lines.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace Employee
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employee firstEmployee = new Employee();   **(2 errors on line for Employee)**
            ApplicationUtilities.DisplayApplicationInformation(); //display the                     header for the application
            ApplicationUtilities.DisplayDivider("Start Program"); //Show heading that the program has started
            ApplicationUtilities.DisplayDivider("Prompt for employee information and create first employee"); //Heading that shows we are ready to input first employee information
            firstEmployee.firstName = InputUtilities.getStringInputValue("First Name"); //Get first name input from the user
            firstEmployee.lastName = InputUtilities.getStringInputValue("Last Name");//Get last name input from the user
            firstEmployee.gender = InputUtilities.getCharInputValue("Gender");//Get gender input from the user
            firstEmployee.dependents = InputUtilities.getIntegerInputValue("# Dependents");//Get dependent input from the user
            firstEmployee.annualSalary = InputUtilities.getDoubleInputValue("Annual Salary");//Get annual salary input from the user

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.Write(firstEmployee.ToString());

            ApplicationUtilities.PauseExecution();
            Employee secondEmployee = new Employee("First Name", "Last Name", 'F', 3, 52000); ////declare an instance of second employee object with overloaded constructor called     **(2 errors on this line for - Employee)**
            Console.Write(secondEmployee.ToString());
            ApplicationUtilities.TerminateApplication();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a namespace and a class with the same name - Employee. That is not allowed.

Comment: @JamieMeyer Incorrect.  One merely needs to use _fully qualified names_ (not that it is recommended)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, Micky. Learned something new today. I am sure that there is a best practice that recommends against this, so as to avoid confusering the compiler.

Comment: @bbravo55 By the way, _[CA1724: Type Names Should Not Match Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182257.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)_

Answer (score 5):

As the error suggests, the namespace and class share the same name. The compiler is confused about what exactly you're trying to instantiate.

Quick fix: Specify the namespace when you create a new instance of `Employee`, so the compiler knows you want to create a new instance of the class *within* the namespace of the same name.

```
Employee.Employee firstEmployee = new Employee.Employee();
```

Right fix: Rename the namespace so you can instantiate the class more easily.

You may also want to read this post from someone who's very knowledgeable about the compiler: [Do not name a class the same as its namespace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx)

FWIW, a tiny app of this size doesn't technically *need* a namespace. But (as Neolisk points out) if you do use one, then [use a good one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx). As your program grows, you could group classes that represent people (such as `Employee`) in a namespace called `Entity`.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that `Employee.Employee` is code smell, same as `Employees.Employee` and generally `Employee` is not broad enough to be good candidate for a namespace. Speaking of good namespace example, `Entity` will probably be it.

Answer (score 0):

Either rename your Employee namespace or rename your Employee class.